# How many words/strings of length 5 can we make using the first 10 letters of the alphabet with at least one repeated letter?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, permutations, combinatorics-on-words

How would you approach a problem like this?
If I were to make words of length 5 from the first 10 letters it would be 10^5 or 10x10x10x10x10, right?
But how do I account for the repetition part? repeated does not mean that they have to be next to each other. It just means that the same letter exists more than once.

Comment: How many are there with no conditions at all?  How many are there with all the letters distinct?

Comment: $$10^5$$ is the total ways...  Just find the appropriate condition and you'll get the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First 10 alphabets of English language are :

A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J.

So, if you want to write the 5 letter string without any repetition, then, the ways should be : $$\binom{10}{5}*5!$$
Also, atleat 1 means : **TOTAL WAYS**(can repeat) - **NONE REPEATING**.

Thus, Total ways = $10*10*10*10*10 = 10^5$

Thus, ***required number of ways is:***
$$10^5 - \binom{10}{5}*5!$$

And that's your answer!